# Angularjs pass data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, imdb

Busy building an video website and i'm currently rewritting the code but i can't get past this issue. So i got a controller.js where i want to do all the request and in my main.js i want to  receive the data and parse is.

So my controller.js looks like:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Movie.services', []).service('Movie', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {

    var API_URL = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/';
    var API_KEY = '?api_key=xxx';

    this.findCast = function( id ) {

        var cast = [];

        $http.get(API_URL, {         

            params: {
                query: id,
                api_key: API_KEY    
            }

        }).then(function(result) {
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(item) {
                cast.push(item);
            });
        });
    }
}]);
```

JSON: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/reference/people/personid/get
And my main.js looks like:

```
app.controller("Cast", function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Page, Movie) {
    $scope.getCast = [];
    var person_id = $routeParams.person_id;


    Movie.findCast(person_id).then(function(result){
        $scope.getCast = result ;
    });
});
```

My question is how can i receive the data from my controller.js in main.js so i can parse it. What i now get is an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I'm not sure if this is the right infrastructure to build my app because in the controller.js i want to make multiple calls for example i want to get the cast, movies, tv series and so on.

Controller.js will look like this (don't know if its the right way to do it)

```
this.findCast = function( id ) { }
this.getMovies = function( id ) { }
this.getSeries = function( id ) { }
this.getPopulair = function( id ) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not returning any Promise from your service, on which you can call then. Do something like this.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('Movie.services', []).service('Movie', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {

var movieService = {
    findCast : function( id ) {
        var API_URL = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/';
        var API_KEY = '?api_key=xxx';
        var cast = [];

        var promise = $http.get(API_URL, {         
            params: {
                query: id,
                api_key: API_KEY    
            }
        }).then(function(result) {
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(item) {
                cast.push(item);
            });
            return cast;
        });

        return promise;
    },
    // getMovies : function(){}
    // similarly write other functions.
  }
  return movieService;
}]);
```

Comment: thanks but how do i call this in my main.js? Saw that you added a var movieService

Comment: you can call as you do now => Movie.findCast()

Comment: Thanks thats what i do. When i log in the promise result function `console.log(item);` i get the results but when i do    `Movie.findCast(person_id).then(function(result){
        $scope.getCast = result;
         console.log(result);
    });` it gives me nothing undefined

Comment: sorry, make small change, write 'return cast' in then function in service. i have made change in the above code.

Comment: Thanks! Still pretty strange when i rune the above code and log into my main.js i get `[Object, 200, function, Object, "OK"]` can't i get directly in the object? http://i.imgur.com/0qIcDWY.png

Comment: because its returning the whole object i guess als kinda strange that all the results are displayed as [0] ... [1] ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are trying to call the promise function `then`, but your function is never returning that promise.

```
this.findCast = function( id ) {

    var cast = [];

// Added return
    return $http.get(API_URL, {         

        params: {
            query: id,
            api_key: API_KEY    
        }

    }).then(function(result) {
        angular.forEach(result.data, function(item) {
            cast.push(item);
        });
//Returned cast, instead of whole response
        return cast;
    });
}
```